RBAC with bicep
Im trying to assing the AD group to my storage account as contributor and also storage blob data contributor using the Servicie principal that is owner at sub level.
param storageAccountName string
param roleId array
param adGroup string
param principalType string = 'Group'

// reference to storage account
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' existing = {
  name: storageAccountName
}

resource roleAssignment1 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = [for roleId in roleId:  {
  name: guid(subscription().subscriptionId, resourceGroup().name, storageAccountName, roleId, adGroup)
  scope: storageAccount
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleId)
    principalId: adGroup
    principalType: principalType
  }
}
]

I get this error
code":"GroupTypeNotSupported","message":"Only security-enabled groups can be used in role assignments."}


The group need to be of type "security". You can check the type in MS Entra

it syas Microsoft 365 :/

@Thomas after changing to different  AD Group which is type Security, i ge tthis error "code":"RoleAssignmentUpdateNotPermitted","message":"Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated"

if you already created manually the role assignment, a random guid was assigned so when running your bicep file, it will try to create a new role assignment with a different name guid(subscription().subscriptionId, resourceGroup().name, storageAccountName, roleId, adGroup). Delete the existing role assignment first and create it again using bicep.

Only MS Entra group of Type Security can be assigned. You can check the group type in MS Entra.
Once you've updated the group type, it should work.
Note: if you've created manually the role assignment, a random guid was assigned so when running your bicep file, it will try to create a new role assignment with a different name (guid(subscription().subscriptionId, resourceGroup().name, storageAccountName, roleId, adGroup). Delete the existing role assignment first and create it again using bicep.
